# NullReferenceException when adding to collection inside controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Playlist playlist)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Session["Playlist"] != null)
        {
            List<int> musicIds = new List<int>();
            musicIds = Session["Playlist"] as List<int>;
            if (musicIds.Count > 0)
            {
                UserProfileRepository UserProfileRepository = new UserProfileRepository(db);
                string Name = this.User.Identity.Name;
                UserProfile User = UserProfileRepository.getModelByName(Name);
                playlist.UserId = User.UserId;

                db.Playlists.Add(playlist);
                db.SaveChanges();

                foreach (var item in musicIds)
                {
                    Music music = db.Musics.Find(item);
                    /*
                     * Error in the line below, it says: 
                     *  Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
                     * */
                    playlist.Musics.Add(music);
                }

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
    }

    return View(playlist);
}
```

Hello everyone, can someone tell what is wrong in my code?
I cant seem to figure out why it says " Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " when both playlist and music are instantiated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That would mean that `playlist.Musics` is null.
You should initialize it in your constructor.

Comment: I solved it. I've just changed that line for "music.Playlists.Add(playlist);"